# Cannot create Attendance in Moodle as there is no such Activity

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to apply face recognition for attendance in moodle for senior project. I've created a course in my Moodle, but I cannot add attendance activity as it just doesn't exist in the activity list. [Activity list looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsOOt.jpg) From search results seems like very strange (and new?)bug.

Github issues doesn't seem to be checked by anyone regularly, so I'm asking  here
https://github.com/danmarsden/moodle-mod_attendance/issues/465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attendance module isn't part of the default Moodle code.

You will need to download and install it.

https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_attendance